# it doesn’t make it any less fascinating or any less important to learn the back story

Tags: sentence-structure

This is an excerpt from [a Smithsonian Magazine article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/when-a-winter-storm-triggered-one-of-the-deadliest-disasters-in-washington-dc-history-180979446/).

> Josh Gibson, founder of the Adams Morgan Partnership Business
> Improvement District (BID), points out that the Knickerbocker story
> “was the banner headline in the New York Times” on January 29, 1922.
> The co-author of the 2006 book Adams Morgan (Then and Now), he says,
> “It definitely got nationwide attention … but it sort of slipped in
> modern memory.”
>
> Gibson adds, “It’s not ‘George Washington slept here’ kind of stuff,
> but **it** doesn’t make *it* any less fascinating or any less important to
> learn the back story.”

I think that 'it' in bold refers to 'the Knickerbocker story' and 'it' in italics to 'to learn the back story'.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first **it** refers to Mr Gibson's claim that "the story is not 'George Washington slept here' kind of stuff" - not of major historical importance.

The second *it* is a [dummy pronoun](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/7/dummy-pronouns) - it doesn't refer to anything specific.

> It is fascinating and important to learn the back story.